# iron-router (Meteor 1.0) Template.layout.rendered not working for private pages

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I use the same layout for all my pages. However, when user is logged in, my layout.js no longer works, specifically the Template.layout.rendered function.

How do I deal with this?

```
Router.configure({
    templateNameConverter: "upperCamelCase",
    routeControllerNameConverter: "upperCamelCase",
    layoutTemplate: "layout",
    notFoundTemplate: "notFound",
    loadingTemplate: "loading"
});

var publicRoutes = ["home_public", "home-public", "login", "register", "forgot_password", "reset_password"];
var privateRoutes = ["home-private", "orders", "orders.insert", "orders.details", "orders.edit"];

Router.ensureLogged = function() {
    if(!Meteor.user()) {
        // user is not logged in - redirect to public home
        this.redirect("home_public");
        return;
    } else {
        // user is logged in - check role
        this.next();
    }
};

Router.ensureNotLogged = function() {
    if(Meteor.user())
        this.redirect("home_private");
    else
        this.next();
};

Router.onBeforeAction(Router.ensureNotLogged, {only: publicRoutes});
Router.onBeforeAction(Router.ensureLogged, {only: privateRoutes});
```

Comment: I've had some problems with older versions of Iron-Router and redirects. It had mostly to do with reactivity stopping to work, just to check - does your code work if you re-load the browser once the redirect has (not) occurred?

Comment: Btw. you could also try to replace this.redirect() with Router.go().

Comment: no, restarting the browser does not help.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean "restart", just refresh/reload the html page once you've entered the new route.

Comment: I understood. On refresh, Meteor first seems to start with user logged-off and the log user. I can see that by the files that run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that Meteor or Iron-Router (I suspect Meteor) has some issues.

**My fix was to use separate layouts for private and public pages such as *layout_private* and *layout_public*.  **

Meteor, when switching between logged in/out, does not re-execute the Template.layout.render (if you use the same layout) and it looses the javascript event listeners somehow in between.

Comment: I suspect my issues are related to the way meteor runs in the dev environment or maybe even live? Looks like on login it would make sense that the layout does not change. But when I login the menu get disconnected from its javascript, and the Template.layout.rendered is not fired. (tested it with an alert() ) However when already logged in (session), starting the app or refreshing it does not fire Template.layout.rendered either. Something disconnects the jQuery listeners. It looks like Meteor in dev loads everything as not logged in and the logs in the user automatically.

Comment: Hope it helps someone. I spent hours on this.